# How to remove a pattern from a string using Regex

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I want to find paths from a string and remove them, e.g.:

```
string1 = "'c:\a\b\c'!MyUDF(param1, param2,..) + 'c:\a\b\c'!MyUDF(param3, param4,..)..."`
```

I'd like a regex to find the pattern `'[some path]'!MyUDF`, and remove `'[path]'`.

Thanks.

**Edit:**

Example input:

```
string1 = "'c:\a\b\c'!MyUDF(param1, param2,..) + 'c:\a\b\c'!MyUDF(param3, param4,..)";
```

Expected output: `"MyUDF(param1, param2,...) + MyUDF(param3, param4,...)"`
where MyUDF is a function name, so it consists of only letters

Comment: Is the `!` always in the string?

Comment: Please explain your input and expected output with more details.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
input=Regex.Replace(input,"'[^']+'(?=!MyUDF)","");
```

---

In case if the path is followed by ! and some other word you can use

```
input=Regex.Replace(input,@"'[^']+'(?=!\w+)","");
```

Comment: Though I wouldn't bet my life on it, since this question is so poorly asked, I believe `MyUDF` could be any string.

Comment: @neoistheone indeed..edited the ans..Though op should come clear on this

Comment: Sorry about it. MyUDF is simply a function name, so only has letters. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Alright, if the `!` is always in the string as you suggest, this Regex `!(.*)?\(` will get you what you want. Here is a [Regex 101](http://regex101.com/r/gI4qJ6) to prove it.

To use it, you might do something like this:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(myString, @"!(.*)?\(");
```

Answer (score -1):

The feature you want, if you are dealing with file paths, is in System.Path.

There are many methods there, but that is one of it's specific purposes.